# Word Collider Animate method

Tags: java

I am currently working on a word collider program. The purpose of this program is that there are two words and once both words overlap each other the words will explode and the letters will be scattered all over the place. Below are the names of the variable names

```
private Text word1;
private Text word2;
// the characters contained in word1
private Text[] charWord1;
// the characters contained in word2
private Text[] charWord2;
```

The problem I have specifically is with the Animate method. Below is the code which follows

```
/**
 * Randomize the position of the two words repeatedly and stop
 * when the bounding box of the two words overlaps.
 */
public void animate()
{
    while(checkOverlap() == false){
        word1.randomizePosition();
        word2.randomizePosition();
    }

    while(checkOverlap() == true){ 
        word1.makeInvisible();
        word2.makeInvisible();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < charWord1.length; i++){
        word1.makeVisible();
        word1.randomizePosition();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < charWord2.length; i++){
        word2.makeVisible();
        word2.randomizePosition();
    }
}
```

When check overlap becomes true I want the words to explode and the letters for each word to be scattered over the screen. I'm not quite sure how I would go round fixing this issue.

Comment: Might help to edit your question to describe what *is* happening (you never actually spoke about that).

Comment: When checkOverlap is false the two words will be randomized on the screen and this code will be executed until the two words overlap. When checkOverlap is true i want the two words to be made invisible and each individual letter will be scattered over the screen. I can provide the full program code if needs be?